# How to load a local HTML file in R with htmltools?

Tags: html, htmltools

I'm having a hard time loading a local HTML file. I tried with xml2 and it  gives an empty file.
With  htmltools and its function includeHTML I get an error message.

> library(htmltools)

> rawHTML<-includeHTML("C:/Users/grouetl/Documents/ProjetsLISE/Camille/Corpusgetz.html")

I get this error message  :

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/grouetl/Documents/ProjetsLISE/Camille/Corpusgetz.html': No such file or directory
```

I tried various version  of relative path (after having set the wd) but I always get the same result..
Thank you for any advice

Comment: There is a typo in your code. It should be .html instead of .hmtl

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but have you tried double slashes? `c://` or `c:\\`  and so on...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved simply by changing the extension of the file from
"file.html" to "file.HTML" !